# Hibernate utf8mb4 charset

Tags: java, hibernate, character-encoding, mariadb

can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Hibernate version: 4.3.11.Final

MariaDb 10.3

In the console i can see:

```
Dec 30, 2018 5:02:20 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
WARN: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x90\xB5 D...' for column 'nick' at row 1
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true&amp;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;character_set_server=utf8mb4</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">login</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8mb4</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
```

When I'm inserting the same value via PhpMyAdmin it works correctly.

Comment: Is the database column `nick` defined to use the `utf8mb4` character set?

Comment: I suppose you  try to store a Java String into a column. What's the string you want to store? Does it begin with the U+1F435 = MONKEY FACE code point, i.e. `value.codePointAt(0) == 0x1f435` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *MySQL* needs `utf8mb4` for `\xF0\x9F\x90\xB5`.  But the outside world calls it `UTF-8`.

```
&amp;character_set_server=utf8mb4
```

`&amp;` --> `&`

`character_set_server=utf8mb4` --> `characterEncoding=UTF-8`